# Importing Android AVD emulator from zip file

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I "export" the AVD by archiving (.zip) both `MyDevice` folder and `MyDevice.ini` from the `$ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME` directory into `MyDevice.zip`. I have a `quick-boot` option set.

On another device I have identical setup (folder structure and environment variables are the same). I unzip the `MyDevice.zip` into `$ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME` and run the script: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.exe" -avd TestDevice3`.

It correctly detects the device, and starts it but it always does cold boot, and all my state from the originally exported AVD is gone.

Is there any other place than `$ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME` where the AVD files are stored which could force the cold boot (the memory is corrupted?) on an identical device? I tried copying the `.adbkey` and `adbkey` from the `%USERPROFILE%/android` and it didn't help.

When I copied an AVD with snapshots, the snapshots were considered invalid, and I was asked if I wanted to remove them.

What am I missing?

Comment: `When I copied an AVD with snapshots, the snapshots were considered invalid` I'd say that's the culprit. As state is the snapshot, if it cannot be used then you will not have it. Have you tried inspecting the AVD to try to figure out why it could be considered invalid?

Comment: It looks like it removes the .ram file (which is included in the .zip package I create). Can't figure out why though... `-verbose` didn't show any logs with extra useful details.